# Prevent UINavigationItem's TitleView from blinking

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, ios11, uinavigationitem

I'm using `UINavigationItem`s `titleView` property to set view in center of `UINavigationBar` of my ViewController. The problem is, when I push another ViewController with same `titleView`, it blinks.

[image: Animation showing Blinking of titleView]

Here is how I set `titleView` inside my ViewControllers

```
let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 40, height: 40))
view.backgroundColor = .red
self.navigationItem.titleView = view
```

What can I do to prevent this?

Comment: What if you set the `titleView` of `self.navigationController?.navigationItem` instead of `self.navigationItem`?

Comment: Where are you executing the above code? viewDidLoad? viewDidAppear?

Comment: You can set the `titleView` inside `viewWillAppear` method which will set the redView before the view is fully loaded but still it won't remain where it was in previous `ViewController` because there is an animated transition going on between each `viewControllers` from left to right or right to left based on `push` or `pop` from UINavigation.

Comment: @karnett I'm executing it in `viewDidLoad` inside parent `UIViewConrtroller` of my two ViewControllers.

Comment: @Matt.kaaj Can't I disable the animation for transition?

Comment: set the animation false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using custom view and adding it as subView to `UINavigationBar`. I'm also setting `UINavigationItem`s `titleView` to blank view to prevent LargeTitle from appearing in place of my view.